# Error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]

Tags: apex, json, rest, httprequest

Myclass

```
public with sharing class soapServiceApexClass {
    @future(callout=true)  
    @AuraEnabled  
        public static void createSOAPWebSevice(Integer x, Integer y){
                partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap myPartnerSoap = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
                partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult partnerLoginResult = myPartnerSoap.login('cnatarajan@datasirpi.com', 'Jeenuuma@123K7l4Xw57BHw4nq5CvKIk524Nb');
                system.debug('partnerLoginResult'+partnerLoginResult);
                soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.SessionHeader_element webserviceSessionHeader = new soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.SessionHeader_element();
                webserviceSessionHeader.sessionId = partnerLoginResult.sessionId;
                soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.MyWebService mySOAPWebservice = new soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.MyWebService();
                mySOAPWebservice.SessionHeader = webserviceSessionHeader;
                Integer z = mySOAPWebservice.Mul(1,2);
                system.debug ('z========='+z);
        }
        @AuraEnabled(continuation=true)
        public static map<String, Object> sendRequest(integer x,integer y) {
            map<String, Object> mapJsonData = new map<String, Object>();

        Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
        string strResponse = null;
         con.continuationMethod='getResponse';
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
       httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
        httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://na156.salesforce.com');
        try {  
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest); 
            system.debug('res body=========='+httpResponse.getBody()); 
            System.debug('httpResponse'+httpResponse);
      
            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
                strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();  
                system.debug('strResponse====='+strResponse);
            } 

        else {  
            throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());  
        } 
      
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {  
        throw ex;  
    }  
  
  if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
        mapJsonData = (map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
        System.debug('mapJsonData ===> '+mapJsonData);
        
    }

    if(!mapJsonData.isEmpty()) {
        return mapJsonData;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }        
 
    
}       
  
}
```

Error
System.JSONException
Error is
Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]

actual body response is- this body response is in html not in json so how to resolve this error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix this line:

```
httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://na156.salesforce.com');
```

You're essentially asking for the login page for na156. This is in HTML.

You're probably looking for:

```
    httpRequest.setEndpoint(remoteSoapEndpoint);
```

Where that value is derived from the value in:

```
String remoteSoapEndpoint = partnerLoginResult.serverUrl;
```

This will look something like:

```
https://instance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/51.0/00D00SOMEORGID
```

Comment: thanks it worked